# Can I expose all the attributes for a terraform resource in a single output variable?

Tags: terraform

I need to expose all the attributes for a specific resource in a single output variable for a terraform module.

Is this doable in terraform?

Comment: do you mean you want to **_concatenate_** all the resource attributes in single attribute? Or, are you looking forward to build a map or list output variable having all resource attributes? Both are possible in terraform. Can you elaborate your question a bit in order for me (or anybody else) to provide you concrete information.

Comment: @Avnish I want to build a map having all the resource attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,

```
output "my_vm" {
  value = aws_instance.my_vm
}
```

But you'll get a ton of weird junk in there so it may not be worth it.

Comment: Strange, this is not mentioned in the terraform official documentation for output variables.
But it works and works well.

Comment: It is definitely strange. It's a useful feature in many cases.

Comment: An expression like `aws_instance.my_vm` just produces an object value representing the resource instance, so the Terraform documentation doesn't mention it specifically because it's just a natural consequence of how the rest of the language features work together. With that said, when writing modules that create abstractions we'll often want to encapsulate the details of resources, which means that returning an entire resource isn't as common as you might think. It's possible to do when you need it, but I would not suggest doing it in all situations.